# RegExp find soundcloud link

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink, chat, soundcloud

I'm trying my best to design a chat, and I want it to find soundcloud links and turn them into a player that can play the song. I know how to use their API for the player, but I can't get my RegExp to work.

My code:`/https:\/\/soundcloud\.com\//gi` only finds the soundcloud bit, but I also want it to find everything that comes after the slash until it hits whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

> `but I also want it to find everything that comes after the slash until it hits whitespace.`

THen you ca use:

```
/https?:\/\/soundcloud\.com\/\S*/gi
```

`\S*` will match 0 or more non-space characters after `https://soundcloud.com/` segment

Comment: This will capture any punctuation after the link. Periods, commas, semicolons, parentheses, brackets, etc.

Comment: @idbehold: Please read the question where OP says: **`I also want it to find everything that comes after the slash until it hits whitespace.`**

Comment: What he wants is to turn a soundcloud link in his chat into an iframe player. Capturing punctuation in the regex will most likely break that functionality. OP might have said he wanted to capture everything after the slash until whitespace, but it is certainly not what he needed.